# Stripe Checkout error loading custom fonts

Tags: stripe-payments, content-security-policy

I'm integrating Strip Checkout without any functional problem (on my local machine up to now). The only problem I encounter is that when the Stripe Checkout script is loading, I get 690+ errors in my devtools console stating :

```
Refused to load the font 'https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/barlow/v1/7cHqv4kjgoGqM7E3t-4s51os.woff2' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "font-src 'none'".
```

I tried to add a CSP meta in my page:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="font-src 'self' https://*.gstatic.com">
```

but the numerous errors persist. How to fix them?

Answer (score 5):

Just curious, when you access 
https://stripe.github.io/elements-examples/

are you seeing similar errors?

It might be a long shot, but what kind of chrome extension are you using now? Seems quite a few folks who have `grammarly` installed have the same issue. if so, can you disable the extension and try again?

Thanks

Comment: When I access https://stripe.github.io/elements-examples/, I also get the errors. 
I don't have `grammarly` installed, but still see these errors.

Comment: In my case it was an extension for changing page fonts (FontAra). By disabling it, problem fixed.

Comment: I had the same errors, wasn't uses Grammarly. But I was using "Pop up blocker for Chrome™ - Poper Blocker". After disabling it no more errors.